# Predictive value of covariance

Tags: covariance

The following [link](http://cs.bc.edu/~alvarez/Randomness/Notes/covariance) provides an equation for the **Predictive value of the covariance** - the fourth subheading approximately. Quoting from the page

> Predictive value of the covariance

```
The covariance of X,Y provides a way of predicting one RV from the other

The best linear prediction of Y, given X, can be shown to be:

    Y - E(Y) = slope*(X - E(X)),

where the slope of the prediction line is given by a covariance ratio:

    slope = cov(X,Y) / cov(X,X)
```

I see the utility of this equation for slope as it can be used to predict one random variable given the knowledge of the other and the relation between the two. But I am unable to work out the math to get the equation for the slope from

> Y = aX + b

where Y and X are random variables with a covariance(X,Y) > 0 and I want to build a linear model of Y as a function of X.

Any help in derivation is appreciated.

Comment: (+1) This result depends on a specific definition of "best."  Evidently, it is intended to be in the least-squares sense of minimizing $E((Y - (aX+b))^2)$. If you look about 4/5 of the way down the page you reference, you will see this explained along with a sketch of the derivation of the result.

Comment: Thank you, I did see that section that provides a sketch. I am not that savvy enough to understand the differentiation part w.r.t to `a` and `b` that is stated there.